# Get the identity from stored procedure

Tags: postgresql

My procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyInsert(_sno integer, _eid integer, _sd date, _ed date, _sid integer, _status boolean)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $BODY$
    INSERT INTO app_for_leave(sno, eid, sd, ed, sid, status)
    VALUES(_sno, _eid, _sd, _ed, _sid, _status);   
$BODY$;
```

i need to  get the output parameter vlaue inside another procedure in Postgresql 11.

```
 CALL MyInsert(1,101,'2013-04-04','2013-04-04',2,'f' );
```

How to get the Return value from another procedure.

Comment: I think than a procedure is not supposed to have any output. A specific code that have to return anything must be a function.

Comment: And if you want to get the value of the id (for example) that is inserted you can use the key word 'returning' : https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/8b5caaa8c3-postgresql-returning

Comment: Whether inout parameters is it possible?

Comment: You will need to explain why you are using a procedure rather than a function when you want to return values. I'm not sure that is clear to anyone.

Comment: thanks @RichardHuxton ..i thought in procedure we can return ..thanks for information i will use function inside procedure to return ,, thanks lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The natural thing would be to use a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myinsert(
   IN _sno integer,
   IN _eid integer,
   IN _sd date,
   IN _ed date,
   IN _sid integer,
   IN _status boolean,
   OUT _id bigint
) LANGUAGE sql
AS $BODY$
    INSERT INTO app_for_leave(sno, eid, sd, ed, sid, status)
    VALUES(_sno, _eid, _sd, _ed, _sid, _status)
    RETURNING id;   
$BODY$;
```

From PL/pgSQL code you'd call it like this:

```
SELECT myinsert(1, 1, current_date, current_date, 1, FALSE)
INTO _id;
```

If you insist in a procedure, you can do it like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myinsert(
   IN _sno integer,
   IN _eid integer,
   IN _sd date,
   IN _ed date,
   IN _sid integer,
   IN _status boolean,
   INOUT _id bigint
) LANGUAGE sql
AS $BODY$
    INSERT INTO app_for_leave(sno, eid, sd, ed, sid, status)
    VALUES(_sno, _eid, _sd, _ed, _sid, _status)
    RETURNING id;   
$BODY$;
```

and call it like this:

```
CALL myinsert(1, 1, current_date, current_date, 1, FALSE, _id);
```

Note that for the procedure it would be natural to define an `OUT` parameter, but PostgreSQL procedures don't support `OUT` parameters yet.